# Начальная настройка CMake проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, project, project-management

Я начал изучать CMake несколько дней назад, но максимум что я смог ( и понял как ) сделать - это однофайловый проект Hello, World!
Я работал исключительно с обыкновенными проектами в Visual Studio до этого момента.
Мой вопрос состоит в том, как правильно настроить CMake проект в самой IDE?

Как мне из подобного вида:

[image]

Сделать адекватный, разложенный по полочкам проект, где не используются фильтры, а создаются папки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне вовсе неудобно/непривычно использовать CMake инструмент и даже ясно для вас я объяснить врядли смог

Comment: Если используете Visual Studio, то нет необходимости использовать cmake. Даже если cmake понадобился для других сценариев сборки, то в Visual Studio можно продолжать работать с обычным проектом. *"Мне вовсе неудобно/непривычно использовать CMake"* - не только вам.

Comment: а если я хочу освоить кросс-платформенную реализацию, но пишу на vs, что мне посоветуете? я не разбираюсь во всяких инструментах, мб есть возможность в VS писать под linux?

Comment: Используйте msbuild для работы в студии на windows, а cmake или другие инструменты - для других платформ.

Comment: Еще если не нужны фильтры в Solution Explorer, то там на тулбаре есть кнопка для переключения в режим отображения папок файловой системы.

Comment: @user7860670 Вредные советы. Система сборки должна быть одна, поддерживать согласованность между двумя - больно.

Comment: Больно, однако менее болезненно, чем каждый раз мучиться с отрыжкой cmake если использовать его для генерации студийного проекта.

Comment: Люди, которые генерируют студийный проект симейком, открывают сгенерированный проект студией и работают с ним, профнепригодны. Студия вполне нормально работает с обычным cmake проектом без прослоек

Comment: Лучше не использовать CMake с Visual Studio, там, как лично мне показалось, багнутый CMakePresets.json

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вы хотите использовать `CMake` в *VisualStudio*, то правильно написав `CMakeLists.txt`, и используя правильный генератор для `CMake` (подробнее [тут](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html)), можно сгенерировать проект *VS* прямо из `CMake`.
2. Если Вам нужна сортировка папок, то в `CMake` каждому таргету нужно присвоить свойство через `set_target_properties` (подробнее [тут](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FOLDER.html)):

   ```
   set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES FOLDER "Utilities")
   ```

   предварительно, в верхнеуровневом `CMakeLists.txt` прописав:

   ```
   set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
   ```
3. Еще полезной может быть вот [эта](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) страничка про `source_group`

## Итого что получаем

Когда мы полностью написали `CMakeLists.txt`, то открываем консоль разработчика *VS*, переходим в рабочую папку и генерируем проект:

```bash
cd D:/path/to/workdir
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -B .build
cd .build
dir
```

И теперь в списке сгенерированных файлов мы можем найти файл проекта для *Visual Studio*, который открывается как и любой другой проект *VS*.

Если говорить про разработку на *Linux*, то *Visual Studio* умеет работать с *WSL* (*Windows Subsystem Linux*) и можно девелопить с `CMake` и под *Linux* на *Windows*.

Comment: Зачем открывать сгенерированный sln ? Это же бред, зачем тогда CMake?

Comment: в этом и суть cmake, если речь идет про кроссплатформенность

Comment: конечно, если вам нужно просто собрать проект не особо вдумываясь, где там какие папки и таргеты, то можно и просто открыть cmake проект, как это позволяет сделать студия

Comment: К слову, возможно VS позволяет открыть cmake проект, сгенерировать его, и сразу применить сгенерированный sln, не перезаходя и не переоткрывая его. Если честно, ни разу не проверял.